# Upgrade from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 Content Database Stuck

Tags: sharepoint-server, upgrade

I am currently trying to upgrade a couple of our sites from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. I was able to do our largest site without much issue, but two of our smaller sites are getting stuck when I try to mount the content database from the old site to the new one via PowerShell. Both are getting stuck at 15%. I am using the farm admin account, so permissions shouldn't be an issue. I have let this run for a couple of days before with no change in the percentage of the content databases.

Database One:

Size: 22 GB

Site Collections: 1

Database Two:

Size: 203 MB

Site Collections: 1

The only error in the logs I have seen refers to the old content database using classic windows authentication versus the new web application using claims, which I know would not be the reason it would be getting stuck, seeing as how the database I was able to upgrade had the exact same error, but upgraded successfully.

What else should I be looking at to see why this may be occuring?

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL logs and the SharePoint logs for the prices to see what's going on? Can you add the appropriate sections to your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not seeing any error then you have to wait. Also you can move out the site collection from main DB to others by using Move-spsite command.

You may also get help from below earlier threads having suggested solutions by experts might helps you to get in more detailed and lets you to get this job done.

[Thread 1](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8aacc31e-e54f-4127-afae-f4d958ac9dd3/sp2010-upgrade-to-sp2013-stuck-at-462?forum=sharepointadmin)

[Thread 2](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2082c850-326f-4546-928c-c692e8982849/powershell-visual-upgrade-stuck-at-395-for-12-hours-no-relevant-error-logs?forum=sharepointadmin)

Hope this helps!